# How do you send your followers to their original homes after sending them to a settlement?

Tags: fallout-4

I've had enough of my followers cluttering up the Red Rocket and am ready for them to just go back home. If you don't select a location to send them when dismissing them (by hitting Tab, B or circle) and have never sent them to a settlement, they go back home. However, if you've already sent them to a settlement, they go to that settlement.

Is there anyway (up to and including console commands) to send your followers home if they've already be sent to a settlement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not averse to mods, one that's just been uploaded to the Nexus yesterday lets you do exactly that - send your companions back to their original homes. It's here:

Companions Go Home - http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/10029/

Answer (score 2):

NPCs do not remember their initial hometown once they are send to a settlement. Because of that, there is no way of sending them back without the usage of console commands.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I can tell, there's no way (without console commands, at least - even then may be iffy) to send them back to their original spawn location after you've sent them to a settlement. Best you can do, if you're tired of them taking up space at your favorite settlement, is to send them to a settlement you don't care so much about. You don't even have to defend it or provide supplies, if you don't have any "normal" settlers there - all followers are "essential" and cannot die. (The settlement's happiness rating will probably lay in the gutter though.)

Comment: "without console commands, at least - even then may be iffy" - Iffy or not, would you mind elaborating? I'd like to know the possibilities and drawbacks to any possible method of doing this.

Comment: @toucan I'm not playing on PC, so I can't confirm for you. It *might* be possible to non-destructively reset them to the point where they're just sitting at home and waiting for you to say "okay, you can follow me now" like when they first joined. But I'd be mildly surprised to find that available. You could probably just re-locate them as-is, but (best case) I expect they'll just start walking back towards their last-assigned settlement. Last, it might be possible to roll-back progress on the last mission before they offered to join you. But that would seem more likely to break stuff badly.

Comment: Know what? I take back the bit about being mildly surprised if you could reset them to waiting at home. If there's a way to manually change an NPC's assigned settlement, and you can remove that assignment, maybe they'll default to home and head off in that direction. Or, if that setting is the same one that keeps them in their house before they start following you, you can possibly send them home that way. Might be safer, for either case, if you had them inside their home location before making those changes.